# Incorrect character in saving process for Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pycharm

I'm creating a new column and this new file and want to save. But in there excel file a column have a character. How can I skip this line the save process or change line to a correct character?

```
import pandas as pd

path = '/My Documents/Python/'
fileName = "test.xlsx"

# open the Excel file
ef = pd.ExcelFile(path+fileName)

# read the contents
df = pd.read_excel(path+fileName, sheet_name=ef.sheet_names[0])
print(df['Content'])
print(df['Engine'])

i = 1
for test in df['Content']:
    try:
        print(i)
        print(test)
    except:
        print("An exception occurred")
        break
    i += 1

df['Test'] = 'value'
df.to_excel('My Documents/Python/Test_NEW.xlsx')
```

Error message

```
data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ude7c' in position 470: surrogates not allowed
```

Comment: in which line does the error occur?

Comment: `File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/New/Main.py", line 26, in <module>` in this line `df.to_excel('My Documents/Python/Test_NEW.xlsx')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Content'] = df['Content'].astype(str)
```